# Поиск индекса значения в массиве ulong[]

Tags: c#

В методе нужно реализовать поиск индекса по `value`. Я написал код, здесь 5 тестов зеленые, 3 красных. В каком месте чего не хватает... не пойму.
Через бинарный поиск и сортировку массива пытаюсь реализовать.

```
        public static int GetIndexOf(this ulong[] arrayToSearch, ulong value)
        {
            if (arrayToSearch is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
            }

            int idx = 0;
            int low = 0; // low
            int high = arrayToSearch.Length - 1; // high

            Array.Sort(arrayToSearch); // сортировка массива

            do
            {
                int mid = (low + high) / 2;
                ulong guess = arrayToSearch[mid];
                if (guess == value) // если guess == искомому значению (value)
                {
                    return mid;
                }

                if (guess > value)
                {
                    high = mid - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    low = mid + 1;
                }

                idx++;
            }
            while (idx <= arrayToSearch.Length - 1);

            return -1;
        }
```

Вот сам вывод тестов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменил код. 6 тестов зеленые 2 красных

```
 public static int GetIndexOf(this ulong[] arrayToSearch, ulong value)
        {
            if (arrayToSearch is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
            }

            if (arrayToSearch.Length == 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            Array.Sort(arrayToSearch); // сортировка массива
            int idx = 0;
            int low = 0; // low
            int high = arrayToSearch.Length - 1; // high
            do
            {
                int mid = (low + high) / 2;
                ulong guess = arrayToSearch[mid];
                if (guess == value) // если guess == искомому значению (value)
                {
                    return mid;
                }

                if (guess > value)
                {
                    high = mid - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    low = mid + 1;
                }

                idx++;
            }
            while (idx <= arrayToSearch.Length - 1);

            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: Как Вы думаете, после сортировки индексы останутся теми же, что и до?

Comment: @Igor я не понимаю как мне это сделать...

Comment: @Igor по сути они должны измениться

Comment: @Igor может мне надо idx присвоить, после сортировки arrayToSearch.Length-1?

Comment: Вы можете словами объяснить, что делает Ваш код и в чем смысл условия `(idx <= arrayToSearch.Length - 1)`?

Comment: @Igor пока (idx меньше или равно последнему индексу) делать то, что в do

Comment: Представьте, что значения нет в списке. Ваш код будет крутить этот `while` столько раз, сколько элементов в списке. Зачем? Может быть прочитать про поиск делением попoлам?

Comment: @Igor, а может лучше почитать, что бинпоиск ничего не ускоряет когда перед каждым его использованием в коде стоит сортировка?)

Comment: @Qwertiy Если прочитать первый комментарий, то можно вообще ничего не читать.

Comment: @Igor, ну можно собрать пары (значение, индекс) и посортировать их)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай по-человечески обычным циклом for и всё. Даже работать быстрее будет.